# TortoiseSVN ignore symlinks

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link, tortoise-svn

I have a project on my Windows 7 machine that contains symlinks. When I try to commit the project to an SVN repository TortoiseSVN fails with "Symbolic links are not supported on this platform".

That's fine and I would like TortoiseSVN to ignore the symlinks. But how?

I played around with the ignore property but since in Windows symlinks have no special names or extensions (they just look like the file they're pointing to), and I couldn't succeed.

Comment: Now I found out that symlinks have the svn:special property. Now it's a question how one can ignore all special files...

Comment: Another workaround would be to exclude 0 byte-sized "files". AFAIK filtering on file size is not supported by TortoiseSVN so maybe the best solution would be to write a script that adds all symlinks to the ignore list one by one...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like SVN 1.8 stopped working with symbolic links. Earlier version of SVN could help with these, if that's an option.

As a workaround, if the symbolic link leads to a folder that contains only other subfolders, you can perform svn operations in the symlink subfolders (that are not symbolic links) just fine.

Comment: It looks like now this issue is caused by OneDrive syncing a file in question which appears to be a symlink to TortoiseSVN. I resolved it by copying the file to a non-One Drive backed location and all worked.